# Problema com clearInterval no React

Tags: javascript, react

Estou com um problema no React ao tentar usar o `clearInterval`. Ele não está parando o intervalo criado por `setInterval`.

Podem me dar uma ajuda e ver no que eu estou errando ou o que está faltando, por favor?

```
function App() {
  let [count, setCount] = useState(0)

  function showTimer() {
    setCount(count++)
  }

  function startTimer() {
    setInterval(showTimer, 1000)
  }

  function pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(startTimer)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={startTimer}>start</button>
      <button onClick={pauseTimer}>pause</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Quando você chama `setInterval`, ele [retorna um ID](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#return_value) que identifica o _intervalo_ criado. É esse ID que você precisa passar para a função `clearInterval`. Atualmente, você está passando uma função que não tem nada a ver com o que `clearInterval` espera. Você pode utilizar uma _referência_ (_hook_ `useRef`) para manter e atualizar esse ID dentro do seu componente.

Answer (score 3):

Como o @Luiz Felipe disse no comentário, você está executando o `clearInterval` na sua função, e não no intervalo em si. Esse é um dos pontos que precisa ser corrigido e podemos fazer isso com o hook `useRef`.

Outro ponto que precisa ser corrigido é que, como esse código é assíncrono, devemos tomar um cuidado extra com o `useState` e fazer uma pequena adaptação para obter o valor correto do `count`. Você pode ler mais sobre isso [nessa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/484880/100416).

Então, o código ficará assim:

```js
function App() {

  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const timerRef = React.useRef();

  function showTimer() {
    setCount(oldCount => (oldCount + 1));
  }

  function startTimer() {
    timerRef.current = setInterval(showTimer, 1000);
  }

  function pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(timerRef.current);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={startTimer}>start</button>
      <button onClick={pauseTimer}>pause</button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#app'));
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

---

Uma outra forma de criar esse contador é com o uso do `useEffect`, mas ainda utilizando o `useState` e `useRef`. Você pode ler [este artigo do Medium](https://medium.com/swlh/creating-a-simple-countdown-timer-using-react-useref-hook-92ae5b6210cb) para ver como ficaria.

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou bastante! Só estou tentando entender o 'oldCount'. No caso seria uma função de callback?

Comment: @rmoraes mais ou menos. A [resposta que eu linkei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/484875/state-retornando-valor-errado-atrasado/484880#484880) explica bem sobre isso, e também tem a [documentação](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-passing-an-object-or-a-function-in-setstate). O que acontece é que quando você passa uma função para o `setState`, você ainda deve retornar o novo valor, mas recebe como parâmetro o valor antigo. Leia a documentação para entender melhor em quais casos isso pode ser importante.

Answer (score 3):

Faltou gerenciar qual variável está armazenando o intervalo (o [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) retorna um valor que é o intervalo criado e esse valor é utilizado para parar esse temporizador) e com a programação utilizando o [Hook useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html) consegue resolver o problema, no seu código tem alguns problemas também que são por exemplo na hora da atribuição do novo valor para o contador e também o intervalor como já relatado, um exemplo básico de solução:

```js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const intervalRef = React.useRef(null);

  function showTimer() {
    setCount(state => state + 1); // ou setCount(state + 1);
  }

  function startTimer() {
    intervalRef.current = setInterval(showTimer, 1000);
  }

  function pauseTimer() {
    clearInterval(intervalRef.current);    
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={startTimer}>
        start
      </button>
      <button onClick={pauseTimer}>
        pause
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

Um outro exemplo com algumas melhorias de tela, fazendo um `toggle` com os botões para visualmente saber o que está acontecendo no componente:

```js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(null);

  const showTimer = React.useCallback(() => {
    setCount(state => state + 1); // ou setCount(state + 1);
  })

  const startTimer = React.useCallback(() => {
    setTime(setInterval(showTimer, 1000));
  })

  const pauseTimer = React.useCallback(() => {
    clearInterval(time);    
    setTime(null);
  })

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={startTimer} disabled={time !== null}>
        start
      </button>
      <button onClick={pauseTimer} disabled={time === null}>
        pause
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```